# Improving Quartz2D drawing performance

Tags: performance, optimization, core-graphics, core-plot

I'm using Core-Plot to perform some charting. However, the performance of the chart starts to get slow after adding 2 hosting views, and attempting to scroll the 3 charts together.

Using the time profiler, I found that for the majority of time is spent on two functions, CGSFillDRAM8by1 and CGSColorMaskCopyARGB8888.

[image: Problem Area]

What can I do to improve the performance of these two functions? It seems that these two functions are the bottleneck in my drawing performance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the blend mode to copy instead of normal, that should help some. You can also change properties of the path such as the miter limit.

If you don't need to save the chart and it's just for viewing, I would just use a CAShapeLayer and attach a path to it representing your chart. That will render far faster than quartz2d.